# how to link openssl libraries in slickedit in LInux env

Tags: openssl, slickedit

HI guys,
I am wondering how to link openssl libraries in slickedit. I have tried various options but no joy. If i run program containing openssl code from command prompt it runs fine which shows libraries are okay but I dont know how to link in slickedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link? what's your meaning of link? 
When build a program? Maybe, you need set the "Project Properties dialog" correctly when you setup a slickedit managed project, or setup your own makefile and add it into slickedit.

BTW, your will get a better answer, when you throw the question to slickedit community.
It is a real sense of community, your will love it when you have slickedit problems.

Comment: Thats done. I have copied crypto.a and ssl.a into lib folder of project and added -lcrypto -lssl in make file and its done.